# Accelerometer, Gravity and Linear Acceleration Query

Tags: android, hardware

I was reading through the sensor event documentation on the android developer site. I am unclear as to whether or not the gravity and linear acceleration sensors are separate from the accelerometer. In other words, can the accelerometer measure gravity and linear acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accelerometer, gravity and linear acceleration sensors all use the same accelerometer, yes, they just output different values based on what they are conveying to the user.

I'd provide source-code proof but it looks like the android git repository browser is down for now.